# Solr Queries are very slow when indexing with a very large index

Tags: tomcat, solr, lucene

I have Solr hosted on Tomcat with background process that reads from pending entities to index
It worked OK for awhile but when the index side grow - now if indexing is parallel to query query became very slow take (more then 4 minuets - it was less then a second).

I know there is a solution of Master\Slave deployment that may solve it but i'm limited to only one machine. 
I can live with slower indexing but i cannot accept slow query
What solr configuration should i apply ?

Comment: Is there any reason why you can not run two solr instances on the same machine? This way you can have a master/slave deployment.

Comment: First of all you'll have to find out where the issues are: are you memory bound (larger caches? more file system caches?) or io bound (disk(s) too slow?)? See [SolrCaching](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrCaching) for where to start on the Solr side.

Comment: Thanks of the master/slave on the same machine - ill check it

Comment: The memory is OK and the disks are fine - the issue is the query is like blocked while index is updated. I want the query to be fast even in cost of missing updates